# best (optimal) way to use style in react js

Tags: css, reactjs, styles

There are so many ways to use style inside react js that it confuses me.
for example :

- Normal CSS
- CSS in JS
- Styled Components
- Sass & SCSS

Are the above methods influencing website **load speed**?
What is the difference between these methods?

Comment: I think this [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/react-components-styling-options/) can be useful for learning the methods and comparing them

Answer (score 1):

Performance is all the same, all of them are translated into plain CSS when you run : npm run build.

CSS has its benefits, because of designer-friendly but you may get some problems by accidentally making 2 classes with the same name(this is when you have CSS split into many files) if this happens it will make debugging a nightmare (been there myself).

Sass has the same problem as css, but it's a way more cooler css :)

Styled-component, CSS in js, may fit a little better on **react component-based world**, because for every "class" that you style a UNIQE className is generated + it gives you more power by having props/state modifying the styles of classes, not like others where for a *backgroundColor* change you will need 2 classes.

There are a lot of ways to do this, best-comparing article that it served me well in my beginning is in here: https://www.sitepoint.com/react-components-styling-options/

Answer (score 1):

Try using SCSS when ever you can. It helps to organize your stylings and will be processed to css any way. So there is literally no mentionable downside.

For simple styling i would recommend normal css classes (in .scss files).

For complex animation or styling logic use javascript in conjuction with existing animation libraries like [framer-motion](https://www.framer.com/motion/). That way you have more control over what is happening and also more possibilities to make your site outstanding and unique.