# Fastest rendering CSS with ReactJS in large project

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

which one fastest way to render CSS with ReactJs, Custom CSS Or style-component CSS package.

Comment: custom css means using .css file?

Comment: This is a too generic question. Results vary based on environment and setup. Please be more specific.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59112437/best-optimal-way-to-use-style-in-react-js/59112460#59112460 take a look here

Answer (score 1):

Pure CSS is faster than Styled-Components.

And the reason is simple if you compile your CSS and generate `.css` and include them in your HTML files the initial paint for browser only takes the time to parse the CSS.

But for Styled-Components even after compilation it has to be added to the head of the HTML and on top of that sometimes you need dynamic values passed to the CSS which all have to be done through JS which will take more time for browser to parse, compile and paint.

Comment: Styles are added to the head once the components are mounted. Thats one the strategies to load what you use and its in runtime not build time.